# WPF UserControl exposing inner listitems

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I'm trying to write a UserControl to display a list of items where each of these items is a title and a group of checkboxes. This whole will represent a form of data where the person filling it in is answering a list of questions with a 1 to 4 value. This all works and binds nicely to the window's ViewModel.

But I've currently got the answers hardcoded in the UserControl as follows:

```
<ListBox
  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalScores}"
  Style="{StaticResource styleOuterListBox}"
  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource styleOuterListBoxItem}">
  <ListBoxItem>Never</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Sometimes</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Often</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Always</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

I would like to set these from the window's XAML or from the ViewModel as they will be different for other forms but can't see the correct incantation. How do I remove the ListBoxItems from the UserControl and use databinding instead?

BigEdit ...

Ok, this is the actual user control (it looks hideous but that's not the point):

```
<UserControl x:Class="BussPerry.Scorer" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BussPerry.ViewModel" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BussPerry">

  <UserControl.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="Gray" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedForegroundBrush" Color="Red" />

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScores">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="styleListBox" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <ItemsPresenter Margin="2" />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="styleListBoxItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <CheckBox Name="CheckBox" Padding="1" Width="60" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </CheckBox>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="CheckBox" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}" />
                <Setter TargetName="CheckBox" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SelectedForegroundBrush}" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>

  </UserControl.Resources>

  <ListBox ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalScores}" Style="{StaticResource styleListBox}" 
      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource styleListBoxItem}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Score}">
    <ListBoxItem>Never</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Sometimes</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Often</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Always</ListBoxItem>
  </ListBox>

</UserControl>
```

And it's being called as follows:

```
<ListView
  Name="listviewScores"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Scores}"

  Margin="5"
  BorderThickness="0"
  Background="Transparent"
  Focusable="False"
  Grid.Row="3">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView
      ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource styleHiddenHeader}">
      <GridView.Columns>

        <GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Path=Index}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn
          DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title}" />

        <GridViewColumn >
          <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <local:Scorer >
              </local:Scorer>
            </DataTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>

</ListView>
```

What I want to do is to move the Never/Sometimes/Often/Always listboxitems from being hard coded in the user control to be databound.

(Suggestions of "you don't want to do it like that" are also welcome!)

Comment: I've been struggling with different techniques to expose properties to inner controls as well. Data binding works in most scenarios but there seems to be some problems when using this type of databinding to Collection of items that may contain ui elements. In this case the databinding on those elements seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

*(one year later...)*

I think your question is similar to mine.  I have come up with a technique to expose the ItemsSource of an inner control on a UserControl.  The link to my question is here:

[Exposing inner Control properties for binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169090/exposing-inner-control-properties-for-binding-in-wpf)

I know that my solution works.  What I don't know is if it violates some sacred 'best practices' out there in WPF.  It 'feels' right though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to bind a collection to a listbox?

It's pretty simple...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}" />
```

where Answers is your collection exposed in your ViewModel.

If you're having trouble creating a custom control that exposes an ItemsSource, then you just need to inherit from ItemsControl instead of just UserControl.

EDIT:
  Some assumptions:

- the DataContext of the ListBox, custom control, or higher parent element is set to your
  ViewModel.
- the ViewModel has a
  property called "Answers".
- the Answers property implements
  IEnumerable<>.

Comment: With this, just make sure you set the DataContext of your usercontrol.  so in XAML:
<YourUserControl ... DataContext="{StaticResource YourData}" />

And YourData contains a property named Answers like SergioL was saying above.

Comment: @Mark - Yeah, I just assumed that knowledge...should have been explicit.

Comment: I really want to bind to two collections, one to the listbox showing the rows and the other to the listbox showing the columns.

Comment: @amaca - perhaps you can rephrase your question.  ListBoxes don't have column headers.  If you custom control contains headers, than you'd need to expose a dependency property to accept another IEnumerable...then you'd have to handle that data in your template.